# remove <unnamed> fields in outline view of xtext eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse, xtext

I have started working on eclipse recently. In eclipse xtext my grammar is:

```
regGrp:
    reg_type=reg_type1 "{" reg_definition+=reg_definition1+ "}"
    ;

reg_type1 :
    name="CONTROL_REGISTERS"
    ;

reg_definition1:
    name=ID '[' regSize=INT ']''{' (regFieldssss=regFieldsdefRule) '}'
    ;

regFieldsdefRule:
    name="DESCRIPTION" '=' descStr=STRING ';'
    ;
```

Then after Run_as -> Eclipse_application in final.sts file I can write a code as:

```
CONTROL_REGISTERS {
    reg [5] { 
        DESCRIPTION = "register" ;
    }
}
```

In the outline view I will get tree as below:

```
         ->final
           -> <unnamed>
             -> <unnamed>
               CONTROL_REGISTERS
             -> reg
               -> <unnamed>
                  DESCRIPTION
```

I wanted to remove those  fields in outline tree.
 Finally outline tree should look something like:

```
                ->final
                  ->CONTROL_REGISTERS
                    ->reg
                      ->DESCRIPTION
```

Please anyone can tell me how to implement this?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your Outline tree given your grammar and your input. Did you use Xtext 2.4?

Comment: No, I am using xtext-2.2.1

Answer (score 6):

The outline is computed by an `IOutlineTreeProvider`. The default Xtext project setup generates an empty stub for you in the *.ui project (named `MydslnameOulineTreeProvider`). This stub inherits inherits from `DefaultOutlineTreeProvider`. Inside the stub you can add customizations. Please refer to the [documentation here](https://eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/310_eclipse_support.html#outline) at for the details of this customization.